# Decrypting rfc2898 password

Tags: hash, cryptography, salt, pbkdf2

I'm in the middle of development and I need to test my login/password api.

Problem is in the database the password is encrypted.

I have the following information.

- key
- iteration
- salt

Is this enough to recover the password?

By the way I can edit these values as well if that will help.

Comment: Simply reset the password. Hashing algorithms aren't meant to be reverse-engineered, they just generate an output based on your input and use logic to reduce collisions. Even your string length gets lost in the hashing process. But there's still hope, an infinite number of collisions exist. You could try inputting random characters alongside the salt, but to encounter a collision there's no telling how long it would take, especially if the hashing algorithm is slow. But because of the salt, precomputed databases aren't gonna help you at all. Just give up and move on.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2 Finding collisions will be difficult due to the computing time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstood, how a password API works. You cannot reverse a properly hashed password, but you can validate an entered password against the stored hash.

To validate the entered password, you need to calculate the hash again, with the same parameters you used to create the first hash. Then you can compare the two hashes, if they match, the password was the same.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reverse PBKDF2, but you could brute-force the common passwords to see if any of them matches. If a random salt is used every time, then you will need to do that for each password independently. If a large iteration count is used then prepare for it to take very long.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should just reset it.

Second, you can recover it if and only if the password was weak (assuming correctly implemented PBKDF2), and you either know which HMAC it used (probably was PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-1 - test with a known password), or you're willing to spend time trying several and hoping.

Try a tool like [oclHashcat](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/) that's designed for password cracking - [note PBKDF2 generic at the end of the list of examples](http://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes) for this, preferably with one or more good GPUs.

Alternately, if you're just testing your password API, you can run the test vectors at [my Github repository](https://github.com/Anti-weakpasswords/PBKDF2-Test-Vectors) through it and see if your results are correct or not.